# Return a view with data after ajax call

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and jQuery.

I'm trying to return a view after an ajax call but **with data** and I don't find the solution.

**JS:**

```
$('#button-recommandations').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url : 'recommandationsSeances',
        data : {
           'idSeance' : $(e.relatedTarget).data('seance')
        },
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        crossDomain : true
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
return view('listeRecommandations', [
     'recommandationAutresActiviteMemeDateHeure' => $recommandationAutresActiviteMemeDateHeure,
     'recommandationsMemeActiviteMemeHeure'      => $recommandationsMemeActiviteMemeHeure,
     'recommandationsMemeActiviteMemeDate'       => $recommandationsMemeActiviteMemeDate
]);
```

It is possible?

Because with the existing code, the code view is return to the ajax call and the redirection is not done.

Thank's for help!

## Solution:

Use `<a>` tag as @charlietfl recommand on comments.

Comment: What redirection? What exactly is or isn't happening? Where are your ajax completion and error handlers?

Comment: What I call redirection is the displaying of the view on the new page. With this code the html code of the view is return to my ajax call. My objective is to redirect on the blade `listeRecommandations.blade.php`. I hope it's pretty clear.

Comment: Returning that view html to ajax implies you want to use it in current page. Is that not what you want?

Comment: No it is not, I don't want use the current page, I want use another page with another blade.

Comment: Then why are you using ajax? Sounds like all you need is for your button to be an `<a>` tag

Comment: Because I have to pass params at my controller but only if a specific button is clicked.

Comment: And with a `<a>` tag I can pass data with GET method?

Comment: Of course you can. `<a href="recommandationsSeances?idSeance=someValue">`

Comment: Ok. So I can do something like this on my JS file? `$('#button-recommandations').attr('href', '{{ url("/recommandationsSeances", $(e.relatedTarget).data("seance")');`